# GTK+ make error: undefined symbol: g_mutex_lock

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gtk, installation

I am trying to install opencv 3.0.0 on a Ubuntu (9.04) computer but need gtk+ first. ./configure goes fine, but when I try to `make` I get a symbol lookup error:

```
/gtk+-2.18.9/gtk/.libs/lt-gtk-update-icon-cache: symbol lookup error:
/gtk+-2.18.9/gdk-pixbuf/.libs/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_mutex_lock
```

I can't use apt-get for these because the distribution is EOL and I'm trying to avoid upgrading if I can because I'm not the only one who uses it and I don't want to risk messing anything of theirs up if I can avoid it.

Comment: Even after EOL it should be possible to get the packages that were available for that version from somewhere and that might be simpler. That being said this system is *horrifically old* and almost certainly *wildly* insecure and really should be put down.

Answer (score 0):

g_mutex_lock is a symbol from glib.

It could be your glib version is too old, or it is somehow missing from the linker line.

- Verify that you are linking against glib
- Check that your glib contains that symbol (e.g. with nm).